# Java Frame with Image and Progressbar

Tags: java, image, frame

I want to create splash/loading screen which shows an simple jpg image and under this image an active progressbar.

But I can't find a solution to code it.

So this is my code so far for the image, it works perfect, but somehow I can't add the progress bar.

Please help me with an code example.

```
static void loadingScreen() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(450, 450);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C://Users//Alex//Desktop//Image.jpg")));
    frame.setTitle("Loading...");
    frame.setVisible(true);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //exception
    }
    frame.dispose();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: "but somehow i cant add progressbar". So what have you tried to add a progressbar? I don't see a problem why it should not be possible.

Comment: the problem is, when i add progress bar and then execute it, that the whole frame is empty...

Comment: then the picture and the progressbar are not shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use a `LayoutManager` with your `JFrame`. So only the last added Component is shown using the whole space. If you add a `JProgressBar` after your Image Label you will only see the empty `JProgressBar`.
You definitely need to learn how to use `LayoutManager`. For now I will recommend you `BorderLayout` to show your Image centered and your progressbar at the bottom.
Another problem with your code is your `Thread.sleep()` statement. Never send your GUI Thread to sleep. Use another Thread that will do the loading.
Here is some sampe code for you.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JProgressBar progressbar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
frame.setSize(450, 450);
frame.setResizable(true);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C://Users//Alex//Desktop//Image.jpg")), BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(progressbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.setTitle("Loading...");
frame.setVisible(true);

Thread loadingThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //exception
            }
            progressbar.setValue(i);
        }
        frame.dispose();
    }
});
loadingThread.start();
```